# relational database: Anything wrong with duplicate keys?

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I have table that looks like this:

```
ID  Prerequisites

BCOR100 None

BCOR150 BCOR110

BCOR150 BCOR220

BCOR200 None

BCOR210 BCOR200

BCOR210 BCOR120
```

As you could notice, the keys BCOR150 and BCOR210 are repeated, would that be in discordance with data modeling principles. I am new to this field and I just learned data normalization. Any extra tips and information are highly appreciated.

Comment: It depends.  If your intent is to have the unique identifier for the row be both of those fields, then you're fine, as no two fields appear twice in that set.

Comment: It also depends on if this table contains data defining Any additional properties for the objects identified by your ID column. If the answer is yes, then take this data set out to its own table, define the ID objects in their own table, and reference that table from the new one.

Comment: BCOR 200: Introduction to MIS (3 credits)

Comment: [Good online links.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004994/canonical-text-on-database-design/24007275#24007275)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing *a priori* wrong with your data structure, with the possible exception of a column called `id`.

You seem to have implemented a junction/association table.  Each row defines one pre-requisite for an `id`.

Because `id` is a rather vague term, I would recommend giving it a more intelligible definition, such as `CourseId`.  In fact, as a general rule, I give my tables names in the plural (`courses`) with the primary key being the singular with `id` appended (`courseid`).

Answer (score 1):

If it the value is *repeated* across rows in the table, while it might be part of a *composite key*, by definition it's not a *key*.

A key uniquely identifies the row (entity) in question.